# Raspberry Pi 3 Miniconda install aarch64 error

Tags: anaconda, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, miniconda

I am entering
sudo bin/bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh
I enter the correct directory, but when it comes to "Unpacking the payload ..."
it gives me an error
"Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh: line 417:  2300 Illegal instruction     "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --prefix "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs"

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install a smooth Conda Package Manager on your Raspberry Pi 3 or 4.

Forget about the Miniconda---------aarch64.sh route because it is really challenging to fix it and make it work after installation. Mambaforge is the key and has worked very smoothly for me.

1. Make sure your Raspbian OS is 64 bit.
2. Get the latest version of aarch64.sh from https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases. When I did the install the latest was Mambaforge-22.9.0-2-Linux-aarch64.sh
3. Install it and make sure the path is added to your .bashrc file.
4. Reboot your Raspberrypi or spin up your .bashrc file to activate conda.
5. Test your conda installation.

Now, let's do it.
Go to your downloads directory and download what you need.

```
cd /home/username/Downloads
sudo wget https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/22.9.0-2/Mambaforge-22.9.0-2-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

Start the installation

```
sudo /bin/bash Mambaforge-22.9.0-2-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

Now during the installation put the installation path as given below. You can name it something else, but to save your time you can just follow me.

```
/home/username/miniconda3
```

Open your .bashrc file sitting at the location /home/username/.bashrc and the the following line in the end of it. And you can skip this step if your installation process already edited your .bashrc file with something similar.

```
export PATH="/home/username/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Considering that your .bashrc is edited, so it need to be reloaded.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, let's test your conda installation

```
conda init

conda env list
```

Happy? Are we? Now? Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are using the  Raspbian OS is 64 bit **legacy**, which is (while I am writing this) approx 5 months older. The one sugested by default seems to be the newest, and as a result conda (and also at present/in my case mamba) fails.
Using the older Raspbian OS everything seemed to work.

Note: you can see the architecture etc. of your system by using the command `uname -a`. It should be `aarch64`